# Select starting node ID in CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cte, recursive

I have following table:

```
create table osoba(
id int primary key,
idNd int,
nazwim nvarchar(500),
)
```

Data looks like below:

```
id  idNd    nazwim
1   NULL    grandpa
2   1   child1
3   1   child2
4   2   grandchild1child1
5   2   grandchild2child1
6   3   grandchild1child2
7   3   grandchild2child2
```

I've got following cte:

```
;WITH ret AS(
       SELECT   *
    FROM    osoba
    --WHERE   ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT o.*
    FROM    osoba o INNER JOIN
            ret r ON o.idNd = r.ID)
```

Select * from ret returns all descendants for each node and starting node:

```
id  idNd    nazwim
1   NULL    grandpa
2   1   child1
3   1   child2
4   2   grandchild1child1
5   2   grandchild2child1
6   3   grandchild1child2
7   3   grandchild2child2
6   3   grandchild1child2
7   3   grandchild2child2
4   2   grandchild1child1
5   2   grandchild2child1
2   1   child1
3   1   child2
6   3   grandchild1child2
7   3   grandchild2child2
4   2   grandchild1child1
5   2   grandchild2child1
```

How to retrieve information about starting node for each record? I would like to get result like that:

```
idStartingNode  id  idNd    nazwim
1   1   NULL    grandpa
1   2   1   child1
1   3   1   child2
1   4   2   grandchild1child1
1   5   2   grandchild2child1
1   6   3   grandchild1child2
1   7   3   grandchild2child2
3   6   3   grandchild1child2
3   7   3   grandchild2child2
2   4   2   grandchild1child1
2   5   2   grandchild2child1
2   2   1   child1
3   3   1   child2
6   6   3   grandchild1child2
7   7   3   grandchild2child2
4   4   2   grandchild1child1
5   5   2   grandchild2child1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the column, in both parts of the recursive CTE.

Starting nodes have the `ID` as startingNode id.

The descendants have as starting node id, the starting node id of their parent:

```
WITH ret AS
  (
    SELECT id AS idStartingNode, o.*
    FROM    osoba o
    --WHERE   ID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.idStartingNode, o.*
    FROM    osoba o INNER JOIN
            ret r ON o.idNd = r.ID
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need level to get a meaningful report

```
declare @t table (id int primary key, idNd int, nazwim varchar(50));
insert @t values 
(1, NULL, 'grandpa'),
(2, 1, 'child1'),
(3, 1, 'child2'),
(4, 2, 'grandchild1child1'),
(5, 2, 'grandchild2child1'),
(6, 3, 'grandchild1child2'),
(7, 3, 'grandchild2child2');
--select * from @t;

with cte as 
(  select id as ori, id, idNd, nazwim, 1 as level
   from @t
   union all 
   select c.ori, t.id, t.idNd, t.nazwim, level + 1
   from cte c
   join @t t
     on t.idNd = c.id
)
select * 
from cte
order by ori, level;
```